# Crossing number of simple undirected graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

There's a well-established [result which provides a lower bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29#The_crossing_number_inequality) for the [crossing number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29) of any simple undirected graph.
However, is there any known result for an upper bound in this setting?

Comment: If the graph has $m$ edges then $\binom{m}{2}$ is tight. You could object that you want to use straight lines, but that is not a requirement for the lower bound version of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following reference could be helpful to you: https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS21
It is from February 2020 and provides the current status of knowledge about crossing numbers, including upper bounds.

Edit: this reference is the reference to a dynamic survey of the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics. It is an extensive survey from Marcus Schaefer, first published in 2013, and with the 4th edition from February 2020.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is generally preferred to sketch the main ideas of a linked article or paper, in case the link becomes dead and to show the main ideas without accessing an external site.